# Почему программисты называют компьютеры «машинами»?

Tags: терминология, история

С момента прихода в сферу разработки ПО, я приобрел привычку говорить «машина» в отношении компьютера. Похоже, большинство из моих коллег делают то же самое. Однако использование этой идиомы в повседневной речи приводит людей в замешательство.

Очевидно, что компьютер — это машина. Однако большинство машин — не компьютеры. Поэтому такая привычка (говорить «машина» по отношению к компьютеру) немного неочевидна.

Так откуда пришла эта практика?

*<sub>Перевод [вопроса](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/394930/319091) с SoftwareEngineering.</sub>*

Comment: Никогда в жизни не называл компьютер машиной. Видимо это чисто английская фишка

Comment: @СергейМишин, я тоже. Правда на ruSO частенько встречается что-то типа «на машине стоит это и то-то…».

Comment: Как раз в русскоязычной литературе частенько встречалось/встречается ЭВМ/ПЭВМ

Comment: @СергейМишин Однако вы только вчера задавали вопрос про "виртуальные машины" :) их почему то "виртуальным компьютером" не называют ... А еще думаю вы только с персоналками дело имели. Поверьте, называть "компьютером" огромный зал, с парой десятков гудящих 
 и щелкающих шкафов, представлявших в совокупности одну _Машину_, язык не поворачивается :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда были изобретены вычислительные машины (англ. computing machines), термин «компьютер» уже существовал и обозначал профессию человека, выполняющего различные вычисления. Вычислительные машины назвали «машинами», потому что они *и были* машинами, в противоположность людям-компьютерам, которые они заменили.

*<sub>Перевод [ответа](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/394937/319091) пользователя [Jörg W Mittag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1352/j%c3%b6rg-w-mittag).</sub>*

Comment: И какое отношение к **русскому языку** (а у нас ведь тоже *машина*, даже такое шуточное название программистов-электронщиков -- *машинисты* было) имеет этот ответ?

Comment: @avp, почему этот ответ должен иметь какое-то отношение к русскому языку? Это вопрос по истории терминологии в области software engineering, она [история] к русскому языку в общем-то никак не привязана.

Comment: Хотя бы потому, что это в первую очередь *русскоязычный* сайт по *программированию* машин. И, кстати, да, русская терминология (в т.ч. слэнг)  тоже есть и своя история у нее была

Comment: @avp, т. к. у нас нет аналога Software Engineering Stack Exchange и вряд ли он нам светит, считаю такой вопрос (и ответ) уместным на сайте (тем более, он довольно интересный). По точно такой же причине на ruSO уместны вопросы по code review. Кстати, лично мне было бы очень интересно узнать об истории нашей терминологии в отношении слова «машина» (применимо к компьютеру, конечно). Буду рад, если вы напишете свой ответ.

Comment: Слово "машина" имеет обобщенный смысл как "устройство с которым здесь работают". Каждая профессия называет "машиной" свое главное устройство. Шоферы называют "машиной" автомобиль. Энергетики называют "машиной" генератор или турбину. Полиграфисты называют "машиной" полиграфическую машину. Ну и так далее. Поэтому логично, что программисты называют "машиной" компьютер.